# Ranking polynomials based on global maxima

Tags: plotting, polynomials, associations

Suppose I have the following polynomials in an association i.e. `<|...|>`, they are:

```
x1 = <|"pol1" -> (354.070 x + 1139.013 x^2 + 2301.827 x^3 + 
       3772.240 x^4)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4), 
   "pol2" -> (353.073 x + 1154.929 x^2 + 2345.483 x^3 + 
       3829.635 x^4)/(354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4)|>;
```

My problem is to rank them by global maxima, to do that I plotted them as:

```
Plot[x1 // Values, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Above]]
```

I used PlotLabels to manually see which curve is higher but then I get: 
[image]

Seemingly I have to use `Placed[{"...","..."}, Above]` to have the labels correctly but I wonder if this can be automated using the association?

Also is there a way to ranked the polynomials in `x1` between `{x,0,1}` without plotting them? I know one can use `NMaximize[x1]` but how does one specify x between 0 and 1.

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[x1 // Values], {x, 0, 1},  PlotLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Above]]` or  `Plot[Evaluate[x1 // Values], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLabels -> Placed[Keys[x1], Above]]`?

Comment: That would put the polynomials as label instead of the corresponding Keys.

Comment: Oh the latter works :) Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to rank the polynomials based on their maxvalue between 0 and 1?

Comment: I used `Table[FindMaxValue[x1[[i]], {x, 0.000001, 1}], {i, 
   Length[xx1]}] // Quiet` but how can I keep the association?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SortBy[x1, - N @ ToRadicals @ MaxValue[{Rationalize @ #, 0 <= x <= 1}, x] &]
```

> <|"pol2" -> (353.073 x + 1154.93 x^2 + 2345.48 x^3 + 3829.64 x^4)/(
>     354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4), 
>    "pol1" -> (354.07 x + 1139.01 x^2 + 2301.83 x^3 + 3772.24 x^4)/(
>     354 x + 1143 x^2 + 2320 x^3 + 3811 x^4)|>

```
Plot[Evaluate[x1 // Values], {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabels -> Placed[Keys[x1], Above]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kglr but the sorting should show pol2 and then pol1, to correspond correctly to plots. is there anything missing there?

Comment: @William, fixed now.